# How to escape quotes when using the command module?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Suppose I have this SQL query:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON secrets.* TO boss@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
```

and I wish to run that query using Ansible's `command` module. On a normal shell, I would do:

```
mysql -e 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON secrets.* TO boss@''%'' IDENTIFIED BY ''123456'';'
```

How can an equivalent be achieved using the `command` module?

I tried this:

```
- command: mysql -e 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON secrets.* TO boss@''%'' IDENTIFIED BY ''123456'';'
```

But that gives an error.

Note that I am aware that the `command` module is not the best way to make SQL queries. The purpose of the question is to find out how to properly give quotes to the `command` module.

Ansible version: 2.7.1

Answer (score 3):

In Ansible 2.6 and above, one can use the `command` module's `argv` parameter to provide the command as a list instead of a string. This method makes escaping unnecessary in the OP's case.

For example:

```
- command:
  args:
    argv:
      - 'mysql'
      - '-e'
      - GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON secrets.* TO boss@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
```

Reference: [command module parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/command_module.html#parameters).

I do not know how to achieve an equivalent for Ansible versions below 2.6. I will leave that for others to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping quotes with `\` should work

`command: "mysql -e \'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON secrets.* TO boss@\'%\' IDENTIFIED BY \'123456\';\'"`

Comment: This results in: `ERROR! failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes: mysql -e 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON secrets.* TO boss@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';`

Comment: `command: "mysql -e \'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON secrets.* TO boss@\'%\' IDENTIFIED BY \'123456\';\'"` - Looks like I missed a trailing quote . Could you please try this?

Comment: That too does not work because Ansible interprets that as `mysql -e 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON secrets.* TO boss@% IDENTIFIED BY 123456;'`. Notice that the quotes around `%` and `123456` are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can define the SQL commands as a variable (folded)

```
---

- name: "Testing"
  become: yes
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    sql: >-
      "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON secrets.* TO boss@'%'
      IDENTIFIED BY '123456';"

  tasks:
    - name: "SQL Test"
      debug:
        msg: "mysql -e {{ sql }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [SQL Test] 
************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "mysql -e \"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON secrets.* TO boss@'%'  IDENTIFIED BY '123456';\""
}
```

See: https://adminswerk.de/multi-line-string-yaml-ansible-I/